# Automatically set/unset category based upon field value?

Tags: add-on, categories, add-on-development, automation

I would like to automatically add blog articles to the category "Video" if a video embed is pasted into the provided field. Likewise I would like to automatically remove blog articles from the "Video" category if the provided field is cleared.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bit of javascript / jquery to set the corresponding category. And you can add it to the publish screen by making an Accessory.